# Final year in computer science bachelors

Tags: internship, education

It is my final in computer science bachelors degree and I would like to begin my career search early, what should I be looking for? I have not done any internships or anything like that.

Comment: Hi Bob R, I'm afraid your question is too broad and hard to answer. Could edit it to be more answerable?

Comment: Personally I would make getting an internship a priority. Most of your competition will have one and not having one will make it harder for you to even get interviewed.

Comment: Internships are the best place to start, even if it's just a month over winter break or something like that.  Also start contributing to open source so you can see what real world code and workflow looks like compared to the bubble of the academia.  Don't know where to start?  Here's a list of trending projects on github: https://github.com/trending  Filter it by a language you learned in school and then contribute a small bug fix or raise an issue.

Comment: I think this question is very general and should be allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to ask this, I know its broad but it pertains to how one can transition from a academic education to a real world career. I feel like being more specific would be more of an advising nature. I was looking for commonalities in others experiences.

Answer (score 2):

No one here can tell you what types of jobs to be looking for, that is up to you. You can work in many different fields and many different levels of the call stack with a CS degree. Figure out what you're interested in and then figure out who is hiring for roles in that area.

I'd suggest checking your school for a Career's department. Most school have something to help soon to be and recent grads find a job.

Check out career fairs in your area. Check if any companies will be coming to your campus to talk/interview.

Basically, make good use of your school's resources to help you get a job or internship.